# Mocking spring model classes that have model classes in them as member variables

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, springmockito

So, I have a class structure as:

```
class ModelA  
{  
    ModelB b; // Also a model object  
    // Getters and setters  
}

class B()  
{  
    ModelC c; // Also a model object   
    ModelD d; // Also a model object  
}
```

I want to mock all of them and use them in a list of ModelA objects. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of options.

1. Don't mock, create the actual model object in the test setup
2. Stub getters and return mock child object, e.g :

   ```
   when(mockA.getB().thenReturn(mockB)); 
   when(mockB.getC()).thenReturn (mockC);
   ```

Comment: Thank you. If I were to use the second option, how would I be able to associate mockA to have mockB as it's member variable?

Comment: hmm... Mock objects don't have member variables. However, you can specify what is returned when `getB` is called on `mockA`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I might go in for the first option if it is not bad practice. Is it considered perfectly okay to setup model objects and use them for the service test? Isn't the mocking rule like, Mock every non-primitive type other than the testing service? Please advise.

Comment: I believe so.The rule applies to the types which perform actions or have some additional logic. If the type just has getter/setter, you can just set it up for the test.